# Почему изображение занимает так много памяти в Android?

Tags: android

Создаю простое приложение "Empty Activity" в Android Studio (Удаляю из него TextView). Далее загружаю в телефон, Android Monitor Memory показывает, что выделено 16.41MB.

Далее для главного RelativeLayout добавляю android:background="@drawable/main_window_background" и заливаю на телефон, и Android Monitor Memory показывает, что выделено 99.87MB.

Изображение "main_window_background.png" имеет разрешение 1280x1920. По моим соображениям: 4 байта на пиксель, 1280 * 1920 * 4 = 9.375МБ.

Почему выделено больше?

Comment: Не замечали, если на изображение наложить какие то эффекты, типа градиента, оно занимает больше даже если число пикселей то же самое и то же 32 битное изображение

Comment: Хотя больше оно занимает только пока закодировано в какой то формат, а битмап одного и тоже размера.